# split an array within an object into separate objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have a json array like this

```
const arr = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "category_name": 
      [
         "category_2",
         "category_3"
      ],
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "category_name": 
      [
         "category_6",
         "category_3"
      ],
   },
]
```

I am trying to group in an array like this

```
[
   { category_name: "category_2", id: "1" },
   { category_name: "category_3", id: "1" },

   { category_name: "category_6", id: "2" },
   { category_name: "category_3", id: "2" },
]
```

I tried this way but didn't get the result I wanted. How exactly do I need to go and what functions do I need to use

```
let array = [];

arr.map((item) => array = [ ...array, {category_name: item.category_name, id : item.id} ] )

result: 

[
  { category_name: [ 'category_2', 'category_3' ], id: 1 },
  { category_name: [ 'category_6', 'category_3' ], id: 2 }
]
```

Comment: Use `flatMap()` instead of `map()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method:

```js
const key = 'category_name';
const data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "category_name": [ "category_2", "category_3" ],
},{
  "id": 2,
  "category_name": [ "category_6", "category_3" ],
}]

const result = data.flatMap(
  o => o[key].map(v => ({ [key]: v, id: o.id }))
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you made the `key` dynamic?

Comment: @Thomas Key that needs to be extracted from current data is the same that needs to be added in new result data so just to avoid duplication I used it like this.